# Proving that $aR + bR = \gcd(a, b)R.$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-domain

How can I prove this:

In a Euclidean domain $R,$ we have that $aR + bR = \gcd(a, b)R$?

**Here are my thoughts:**

I know that if $d = \gcd(a, b),$ then it can be written as a linear combination of $a,b$ but I do not know how will this help me in the proof.

Comment: Which inclusion do you have a problem with?

Comment: Pls show what have you tried?

Comment: @IgorRivin I will edit my question with my thoughts.

Comment: I will edit my question with my thoughts.@JitendraSingh

Comment: The form is very much like Bezout theorem.